# What are the odds of getting at least two matching faces on 4d6?

Tags: probability

Looking for the odds of getting at least 2 of the numbers on 4 dice to be the same. As such, I think:

- There are 6 ways to create doubles - dice $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(1,4)$,
  $(2,3)$, $(2,4)$, $(3,4)$
- There are 3 ways to create triples - dice
  $(1,2,3)$, $(1,2,4)$, $(2,3,4)$
- There is 1 way to create a quad, obviously, with all dice.

Then, am I correct in saying the odds would be:

$$\frac{(6*6*5*4)+(3*6*5)+6}{6^4} = \frac{816}{1296} \approx 0.63 $$

Edit: the correct answer as identified in the comments below is $1 - \frac{6\frac{4}{~}}{6^4}$

Comment: You forgot about the possibility of *two-pair*, for example if the dice results were $3,3,5,5$.  That being said, the far easier approach here is to just consider the opposite outcome.  The probability that all dice are different.  The answer you want is just $1$ minus that.

Comment: For what its worth, this is just a much smaller version of the "birthday problem"... here with $6$ possibilities rather than the usual $365$.  If you were to use your approach here of breaking into cases for the birthday problem with say... $30$ people... you will enter "*case hell*"... having to break into far too many different cases to be able to manage effectively.  Your safest bet is to use the approach I alluded to before of finding the probability of the complement instead.

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz. So it's just 1 - (6*5*4*3)/6^4 then?

Comment: Yes, and using the notation [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) this can be rewritten more cleanly as $1 - \frac{6\frac{4}{~}}{6^4}$, and for the birthday problem case of 30 people, the probability at least two people share a birthday (*assuming 365 days a year equally likely, ignoring leap years*) is $1-\frac{365\frac{30}{~}}{365^{30}}$

Comment: Again, you could have corrected your approach, but it is not recommended for generalizations.  If we do it anyways, you'd find you needed the *twopair* outcomes, there being $3\cdot 6\cdot 5 = 90$ missing from your numerator.  Also, your triples you missed (1,3,4), there should have been $4$ triples possible (*which should have been calculated directly with binomial coefficients as $\binom{4}{3}=4$*) for a corrected total of $\frac{6\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4 + 4\cdot 6\cdot 5 + 6 + 3\cdot 6\cdot 5}{6^4} = \frac{13}{18}$, same as $1-\frac{6\frac{4}{~}}{6^4}$ gives